# Method dispatch in Java: why can't it differentiate between interface and class arguments at runtime?

Tags: java, oop, overloading, java-17

I'm working on a Java program that has an interface `I` and classes `A` and `B` that implement it. I also have another class implementing `C`  that has 2 method with one argument: one that accepts an object of A and another that accepts an object of B.

```
  interface I {}
  static class A implements I {}
  static class B implements I {}
  interface C {
    String map(A a);
    String map(B b);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Injected at runtime;
    C mapper = getInstance();
    I a = new A();
    I b = new B();
    // This fail at compilation 
    String result = mapper.map(a);
  }   
private static C getInstance() {
    return new C() {
      @Override
      public String map(A a) {
        return "a";
      }
      @Override
      public String map(B b) {
        return "b";
      }
    };
  }
```

When I try to call the method of C with an object of A or B I get the following error:

```
java: no suitable method found for map(Main.I)
    method Main.C.map(Main.A) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Main.I cannot be converted to Main.A)
    method Main.C.map(Main.B) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Main.I cannot be converted to Main.B)
```

Even if we say that other instances of type `I` can be passed to mapper this should be fixed with `sealed interface I permits A, B {}`

Why there is no method dispatch at runtime in Java ?
**My question is why it's not possible in java more then "Why it didn't work"**

Comment: show the complete error message and a [mcve]

Comment: You added the error message, good. Now post a [mcve].

Comment: Which overloaded method is used is determined by the _declared type_ (`I` for both variables), not the _actual_ type. Even if `I` is limited to `A` and `B`, the compiler still won't know which of the two to call.

Comment: Your methods expect an argument of type `A a` or `B b` but you try to pass `I a`.  Resolving which method gets called is done during compile time so it doesn't matter what your object is during runtime (or that in the code above it is only possible to be of a certain type). As far as the compiler is concerned `a` is `I a` and nothing more and there is no method that accepts `I` as an argument.

Comment: If both `A` and `B` extend/implement `I` but your method only accepts `A` or `B`, then you cannot pass an `I`. What if there is a `C` that also implements `I`? then there's no method for it. If you define a third method `String map(I b);`, then dynamic binding would kick in.

Comment: Even though *you know* that `a` contains an instance of A, the *compiler* does not know that.  You told the compiler that `a` contains an object of type I.  The compile does not *execute* any code;  the compiler merely compiles it.  The compiler doesn’t know that you assigned an A object to `a`.  The compiler doesn’t have any way to be know whether another assignment elsewhere in the code might place a different object in `a` whose type is not A.

Comment: @f1sh  even with sealed interface it doesn't work. because if I permit only A and B to implement I why at runtime there is no kind of type matching ? adding ``` String map (I b) ``` makes code compile but the at runtime only this method will be executed

Comment: @maroodb "why at runtime there is no kind of type matching ?" <- Because that's just how method overloading works. Deciding which of the overloaded methods to call is always done during compile time. There simply is no such thing as runtime-overloaded-method-call-decision-making in java. If you want a decision which methods gets called during runtime you need to use polymorphism and not method overloading.

Comment: @maroodb In case you are wondering how a solution via polymorphism would look like, here is a simple example of how it could be done: https://ideone.com/GR7Oob

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, Thanks for the proposed solution, but actually I have some constraints: A and B are domain entity they implement a marker interface. Mapper is a class at presentation layer it should map domain objects to presentation objects. I need to map list of different domain objects (which they only implement the same marker interface) into presentations DTOs. So I can't add mapping related logic inside A and B

Comment: I was able to get similar result using visitor pattern I will publish it in response

Comment: Try to write your question title to be clear and specific enough that someone doesn't need to read the question body to know what the word "this" is being used to refer to.

Comment: My first attempt at a more concrete title: "Why can't method dispatch select between an argument accepting an interface and a concrete type implementing same?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been several answers to the effect of "because overload selection is done at compile time based on the static types of the arguments, not at runtime based on the dynamic type of the arguments."  These statements are 100% correct; this is how overloading works, and how it was designed to work.  Multiple dispatch ("multimethods") were well known at the time Java selected single (receiver-based) dispatch.

A reasonable next question is *why* was it done this way?  There are several reasons why this was a slam-dunk in 1995:

- **Predictability.**  It is a simplicity benefit if a given call site always corresponds to exactly the same (virtual) method.
- **Safety.**  There are cases when there is no "best" overload.  Determining this at compile time, with a clear error message, is preferable to having the program fail at runtime only when an unexpected combination of inputs is passed.  Having every method dispatch potentially throw an "no most specific overload" exception would make the language less reliable.
- **Performance.**  Overload selection is potentially expensive; better to perform this up-front, at compile time, and not burden the runtime with it.
- **Simplicity.**  The interaction of overloads and overrides would be significantly more complicated than they are today, because, for example, we'd need more rules to break ties between "more specific method in superclass and overridden candidate in subclass".  This would lead to more surprising interactions.
- **Practicality.**  True multiple dispatch is rare; embracing multi-parameter dispatch would likely complicate the language and runtime in excess of its expressive value.

In 2023, compiler and runtime technology have improved quite a bit, so the balance between compile-time overload selection and runtime dispatch  might have shifted a bit, but overall this remains a sensible and pragmatic tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not possible in java to have this kind of overloading, I found a solution which could resolve a similar problem, using Visitor pattern.

First let's say that the code below represent our domain object and we wont add any external dependency or implementation details to it (like mapping details)

```
// Domain Layer
 interface I {
    void accept(VisitorMapper visitorMapper);
  }

  static final class A implements I {
    @Override
    public void accept(VisitorMapper visitorMapper) {
      visitorMapper.visit(this);
    }
  }
  static final class B implements I {
    @Override
    public void accept(VisitorMapper visitorMapper) {
      visitorMapper.visit(this);
    }
  }

interface VisitorMapper {

    void visit(A a);

    void visit(B b);
  }
```

As we can see in domain Layer there is no external dependency or implementation details of mapping logic.

In the code below we will represent the web layer, and we want to map our domain objects into Json representation and we print it to a PrintStream.

```
// Web Layer 
  static class JsonVisitorMapper implements VisitorMapper {

    private final PrintStream out;

    JsonVisitorMapper(PrintStream out) {
      this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(A a) {
      out.println("""
          {"a": "a"}
          """);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(B b) {
      out.println("""
          {"b": "b"}
          """);
    }
  }
```

And now let's wrap it up!
Here is our main application :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VisitorMapper mapper = new JsonVisitorMapper(System.out);
    I a = new A();
    I b = new B();
    List<I> domainsObjects = List.of(a, b);
    domainsObjects.forEach(obj -> obj.accept(mapper));
  }
```

And by this now we can map a list of different domain object to different representation in the same stream.

PS :
PrintStream can be actually the `ResponseWriter` or a `List` or anything mutable.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the 'identity' of a method is **not just its name**. It's actually its name, *and* the type it is in, *and* the types of the parameter names (and  at the class file level, even the return type).

Thus, given `map(I i)` and `map(A a)`, those methods are *completely different*. It is **not possible** to get dynamic dispatch going for the same reason it's not possible to make a call to `.foo(x)` somehow result in a call to `.bar(x)`.

Java does have dynamic dispatch, of course. There is a difference between overriding (which does dynamic dispatch) and overloading (which does not).

This is where java *does* engage in dynamic dispatch:

```
class Parent {
  void foo() { System.out.println("Parent!"); }
  void bar(Number n) { System.out.println("Parent!"); }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  void foo() { System.out.println("Child!"); }
  void bar(Integer n) { System.out.println("Child!"); }
}

Parent p = new Child();
Number n = 5;
p.foo(); // prints 'Child!'
p.bar(n); // prints 'Parent!'
```

`foo()` in Child is an *override*. You can stick `@Override` on it and javac will compile it without complaint. (`@Override` doesn't make a method an override; it is merely compiler-checked documentation: javac refuses to compile a method with that annotation if it doesn't override anything. That's all it does. It's 'error or no-op').

`bar(Integer)`, however, is *not an override* - if you stick that annotation on, it would cause a compilation error. Given that `bar(Integer)` is a completely different method, `p.bar(expr)` where `expr` is of type `Number` (even though that expression resolves to a reference to an object of type Integer, that is irrelevant, the compiler cannot know that, that's a runtime thing).

If you want this, it.. kinda looks ugly. Would go something like:

```
interface C {
  String map(I i);
}

private static C getInstance() {
  return new C() {
    public String map(I i) {
      if (i instanceof A) { ... }
      else if (i instanceof B ) { .... }
      // and so on
    }
  };
}
```

Note that java20 introduces some convenient features such as `i instanceof A a` (which declares a variable of type `A` named `a`), and pattern-switch which lets you write one `case` statement per type (also making a variable that is 'pre-cast' for you).

Comment: I got it. I understand now why it doesn't work. regarding the solution using ``` instance of ``` it looks ugly yes that's why I avoided. I actually added an answer of how I can obtain something similar with using if blocks

Comment: @maroodb soon you'll be able to use "pattern matching for switch statements" to get rid of the else-if statements and also get some exhaustiveness checking (letting the compiler tell you if you've covered all cases).  Whether that's actually less ugly being a matter of taste to some degree. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

type of object `a` is not known at compile time, the compiler cannot determine which version of the map method to call, so it is ambiguous

To fix this,

Option1: change the type of `a` to be more specific

- (e.g., A a = new A() or B b = new B())

Option2: modify the map method of the C interface to accept any object that implements the I interface

- (e.g., String map(I i)).

Comment: The first option is not what I am looking for, the second option will result that every call to ``` mapper.map ```will cal the  ```String map(I i)``

Comment: is it not working with Second Option ?